# I need to integrate two sites, what's the best way to carry over login information?

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, get, integrate

So, I have two sites, sites A and B. I need to make B part of A. I did this by adding a module to A, and within that module, an iframe that contained a link to B. So, effectively speaking, B can still be accessed as a standalone site, but it can also be accessed through A. 
Now, both sites require a login to allow access. I need to bypass the login for site B when it is accessed through Site A. I managed to bypass it, but only if the two sites are hosted on the same server (I used session variables), but now I need to be able to bypass the login screen on B regardless of the server it is hosted on. 
So, how do I do this?

At first I thought cookies, but cookies are domain specific, the two sites might be hosted on separate domains.

Is there way a to use GET? So, Site A calls a url with the username written in the url, and then site B reads the url, parses it and logs in accordingly. I have no idea how I can implement this, what kind of url would I have to call, what kind of php code would Site B need, and lastly, how do you make something like this secure?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Treffynnon - I like Treffynnon's answer. Sending only the user ID would make your site vulnerable. Someone could log in to the second site by just sending an user ID to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a UUID with a hash to site B. The hash should be something that only both servers will know and can decode so something like the following should work.

### On site A

```
<?php
$salt = 'ashfiu8435t43434t fgfjgfgfuguSGDSBDY77;';
$uuid = ''; // this should be set to the users ID
$hash = sha1($salt . $uuid);
?>
<a href="http://siteb.com?hash=<?php echo ($hash); ?>&uuid=<?php echo $uuid; ?>">Site B</a>
```

### On site B

```
<?php
$salt = 'ashfiu8435t43434t fgfjgfgfuguSGDSBDY77;';
$uuid = $_GET['uuid'];
$sent_hash = $_GET['hash'];
$local_hash = sha1($salt . $uuid);

if($sent_hash === $local_hash) {
   echo 'Logged in! Yay!';
} else {
   echo 'Authentication failed';
}
```

You should make the hash more difficult to fake or figure out and make it expire after a given time so that people can't just save hashes and re-use them or pass them about. I have deliberately kept it simple to show this would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is pretty much exactly what I am looking for, what would I need to append to the url if I wanted to send over a second field as well?

Comment: @zermy - If you want to send additional fields, you can append them like "&field2=contentfield2&field3=contentfield3" etc. Just add the "&" in between fields.