# How can I ensure the right user is logged in when a website is called by a website

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

Sorry for the strange, recursive wording of the title, but I couldn't think of a better title. 
As I have alluded to before, I have 2 websites A and B, and I am integrating B into A, so that B is still accessible as a standalone site, but also as part of A (in an iframe). Both sites have their login screens. I needed to bypass the login screen for site B when it was accessed from A. I got this done, as follows:

First A checks if the location of B is the same as a (i.e. they are running on the server), if this is true, then the login information is stored in session variables and checked on b.

If the location of B is a different server, then the login information is sent through the url (see here: [I need to integrate two sites, what's the best way to carry over login information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473884/i-need-to-integrate-two-sites-whats-the-best-way-to-carry-over-login-informatio) ), this is probably not secure given that the url can be seen in the source code, but I couldn't think of a better solution.

When website B is called, index.php is called, and index.php checks if a user is logged in or not (whether the session variable is set or not), if no user is authorized, index.php calls check.php which checks the authentication data sent by site a. If the data is a-ok, check.php authenticates the user and once the script ends we are back at index.php.

Now, the only issue is that say if user ADMIN logs into website a, then clicks the link for website b, website b is displayed and he is now logged in as admin on both sites. After doing some stuff, ADMIN logs out of SITE A WITHOUT logging out of site b. Then, his boss, SUPER ADMIN walks over, shoves ADMIN of his seat and logs into site a. SUPER ADMIN then clicks on the link to site b, only to find that he is logged into site b as ADMIN. At this point, he picks up the phone, calls me, and proceeds to yell profanities at me.

So, it isn't the most serious of issues, but it would be nice to solve. One solution I have in mind is to add a website b id field to each user of site a and send this in the url as well. So, when check.php is called, it stores the id field in a SESSION variable. So, when index.php is called again by website a, it checks if the Session variable is set, and if it is, then it compares the set variable to the new one being sent by $_GET. If the URL is different, it destroys the session, and includes checks.php, I can probably implement this solution, but it will take a bit of work, and I am not sure if this is a good idea or not, so I wanted to ask if there is another better way, or tips for the above solution.

Thanks for your time, have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Make the servers communicate with eachother. When a user wants to access site B through site A, send him to server A first. Server A negotiates some sort of login-token directly with server B before it redirects the user to site B with the newly created login token. The server to server communication is not so easily intercepted, so you can send the user info in plain text, but you can also encrypt this communication if you find it neccessary.

When SUPER ADMIN arrives, he will get a new login-token, telling server B to terminate the active session, and log in the new user.

It's not super secure, but it's quite simple and should work well enough for this scenario...

Comment: Interesting, uhh, sorry, this will sound silly, but how do I get the servers to communicate with each other? As in, is there a php function which allows you to send and receive tokens?

Comment: You can use php's file handling functions. For example `file_get_contents`. Like this: `$token = file_get_contents('http://www.server-b.com/token.php?user=ADMIN');` token.php on server B should then check the IP of the request, and if it is server A it can create a token and write it back to server A with a `echo $token;`

Comment: The nature of the token will affect the safety of this approach. Ideally you should have a db-table with user information, tokens and timeout information. The token should normally be used almost instantly, so the timeout can be low. If a database is not an option, you could use a time based hash combined with a uuid, as in your example. The time part of you salt could be the current time rounded to the nearest minute. When the login request comes, the server must check for the current and the previous minute, making the effective timeout anything between one and two minutes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will do my best to research all this token stuff, and try to implement it, it will probably take some effort to get it to work. 
I still don't totally get how it works, is the token first created on Server A? When you use file_get_contents, you get a string, right, so server B's html with that login is stored inside a string? And then how can Server check the IP of the request? 
Thanks again!

Comment: My idea was to create the token on server B. I assume both servers share a common user base. Server A provides user information, and server B returns a token. Site A redirects the user to site B with the token. Server B checks/decodes the token and log the user in if the token is valid.